# Detect invalid JSON files in directory tree

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, xargs, json

I want to fail a build if the directory tree contains a JSON file which is invalid according to the [`jsonlint` package from NPM](https://npmjs.org/package/jsonlint).

I thought this would be as easy as running:

```
find . -name \*.json | xargs jsonlint -q
```

I knew I had a badly formed JSON document on the disk, and this doesn't pick it up.

Further investigation shows that the `find` command works as expected, however the `jsonlint` executable is only being called once (and the first JSON file is correct.)

Is there a better way to do this, or is there something I need to learn about `xargs` here?

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 Server and can install packages if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like `jsonlint` cannot deal with multiple files:

```
$ jsonlint -h

Usage: jsonlint [file] [options]

file     file to parse; otherwise uses stdin
```

Note that it always says *file*, never *files*. When you run a command and pipe its output to `xargs` as you have done, `xargs` will simply concatenate all the output of the command and pass it as input to whatever you have told it to execute. For example:

```
$ printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n"
foo
bar
baz
$ printf "foo\nbar\nbaz\n" | xargs echo
foo bar baz
```

That shows you that the command executed by `xargs` was

```
echo foo bar baz
```

In the case of `jsonlint`, what you want to do is not `jsonlint -q foo bar baz` but

```
$ jsonlint -q foo
$ jsonlint -q bar
$ jsonlint -q baz
```

The easiest way to do this is to use `find` as suggested by @fede.evol:

```
$ find . -name \*.json -exec xargs jsonlint -q {} \;
```

To do it with `xargs` you need to use the `-I` flag:

```
   -I replace-str
          Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
          names read from standard input.  Also, unquoted  blanks  do  not
          terminate  input  items;  instead  the  separator is the newline
          character.  Implies -x and -L 1.
```

For example:

```
$ find . -name \*.json  | xargs -I {} jsonlint -q {}
```

Or, to deal with strange names (that contain newlines for example) safely:

```
$ find . -name \*.json -print0  | xargs -0I {} jsonlint -q '{}'
```

Comment: On ubuntu, when you `sudo apt-get install jsonlint`,  the command is `jsonlint-php` and you do not need the -q flag . You can use `find . -name \*.json  | xargs -I {} jsonlint-php {}` .

Answer (score 4):

The current answers to this question are incomplete since the suggested commands will not print the name of the invalid file. Also, *jsonlint* is one hell of a slow tool.

Here's a much **much** faster alternative which shouldn't require additional installations on most systems:

`find . -name \*.json -exec echo {} \; -exec python -mjson.tool "{}" \; 2>&1 | grep "No JSON" -B 1`

Answer (score 2):

Use the "-exec" option to execute on each find recurrence. The recurrence file is passed as {} and use \; to finish the command.

So something like:

```
find . -name \*.json -exec jsonlint {} \;
```

On the output you could do an inverse grep of ": ok". something like:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec jsonlint -v {} \; 2>&1 | grep -q -v  ": ok"
```

This will return false if there is one not ok or true if there is. The 2>&1 is ugly but errors are written to stderr at least on my jsonlint version

Answer (score 0):

I recently also wanted to discover and lint all my JSON files (while ignoring a specific directory). I couldn't find a tool I wanted so I ended up making my own python module and put it up on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/JsonFNL/.